# What's this question duped to?

Tags: support, duplicates, close-reasons

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84009/why-gsettings-isnt-enough-to-reset-my-nautilus-settings) is closed as a duplicate, but as a duplicate of what?

Comment: berdario, the question owner, [edited](http://askubuntu.com/posts/84009/revisions) out the duplicate link.  From what I can see, it probably shouldn't have been closed, but I'll leave it up to the moderators to reopen.

Comment: Most probably [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15262/editor-for-gsettings).

Answer (score 1):

> berdario, the question owner, [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/84009/revisions) out the duplicate link. From what I can see, it probably shouldn't have been closed, but I'll leave it up to the moderators to reopen. – Jarrod Dixon♦ Mar 2 at 2:58

And:

> Most probably [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15262/editor-for-gsettings). – nitstorm Mar 2 at 5:35

Just removing from unanwered listings since it has a valid answer.